# Does Collections.sort in GWT client code cause JavaScript to bloat?

Tags: java, gwt, arraylist

We've taken steps to ensure we use concrete implementations of List<> in our GWT client code to avoid generating excessive JavaScript. (Note: I know we could black list types instead.)

If we use Collections.sort client-side, will this cause the same bloat? Or will it recognise that we only use it for ArrayLists and generate the code accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `ArrayList` instead of `List` *only* prevents bloat when referencing those types as RPC serializable. To achieve that, avoid listing `List` in the arguments or return type of any RPC interface, or in the fields of any class you define that is serializable.

Doing it anywhere else (including when passing to util methods like `Collections.sort`) is unnecessary - the compiler is actually smart enough to work those cases out and simplify your code as it compiles.

The reason for this difference is pretty straightforward - lets look at the compiler as three basic steps.

- First, we generate any code we need (`GWT.create()` is the clue to GWT to say 'please generate the implementation for this type').
- Then, since we know all possible Java code that might be required to run the application, we optimize the entire project, and can simplify.
- Finally, we translate the simplified/optimized Java into JavaScript.

The generation of the serializer code happens in the first step, but the 'type tightening' and 'method call tightening' optimizations happen in the second step. If it were the other way around, the compiler might decide to remove some code that doesn't appear to be used, but then the RPC generation code decides to use it, after it is gone.

So it is *only* necessary to be extra-specific about your types when making RPC interfaces and serializable classes. Anywhere else (like removing Collections.sort) is premature (and useless) optimization.